# How to peek into Intent Extras in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

I have an application that starts `Activity` with extras. I would like to see what  extras are inside Intent. Both applications (calling and called) are not written by me.

Comment: Temporarily replace the target with an imposter that dumps this info to the log.

Comment: @ChrisStratton and what if component is explicitly set in intent?

Comment: That was assumed to be the case and is why you install your logger as an imposter - ie, something having the same class and package name as the intended target, which of course you will have to remove first.

Comment: @ChrisStratton which can be tough if its system application or Play Services app :)

Comment: Beyond Mr. Stratton's suggestions, or seeing if there is a custom ROM that you can use that can record this stuff, I am not aware of any other option.

Answer (score -1):

Send the data first:

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.class);
i.putExtra("parameter", yourData)
startActivity(i);
```

To get the data :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String data = i.getStringExtra("parameter"); //you can do for integer, etc
```

Comment: This bears no relevance to the clear circumstances of the question actually asked.  Voting to delete.